# in splunk search How to get all instances that has a field without any value

Tags: search, isnull, splunk

This is the line in my log file.I want to get all searchTerms that do not have a value for PAMapped

> 2012-10-29 11:20:21,711 -
>   searchTerm=speeding&location=Soperton%2C+GA&PAMapped=

This is the search I gave.

> index=savvis-varnish host="dell1000a-12"
>   source="/flocal/logs/lawyers.findlaw.com/search-mapping.log" NOT
>   PAMapped=* earliest=-1mon@mon

But it does not return all instances. It returns only one.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the `PAMapped` field has already been extracted...

I would use the `fillnull` command ([docs](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fillnull)) to add a generic value to all empty values in this field. This would then allow for much simpler filtering on the fields which have a NULL value, like in your use-case.

For example you could probably do something like:

`index=savvis-varnish host="dell1000a-12" source="/flocal/logs/lawyers.findlaw.com/search-mapping.log" earliest=-1mon@mon | fillnull value=NULL PAMapped | search PAMapped=NULL`

This may not be the most effecient search, but it may give better potential for expansion.

You could also try using `where` command to filter results ([docs1](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Where) & [docs2](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/SearchReference/CommonEvalFunctions)), something like the following may work:

`index=savvis-varnish host="dell1000a-12" source="/flocal/logs/lawyers.findlaw.com/search-mapping.log" earliest=-1mon@mon | where isnull(PAMapped)`

Hope this helps.

P.S. You can find more helpful and prompt responses over at SplunkBase the official Splunk forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`index=savvis-varnish host="dell1000a-12" source="/flocal/logs/lawyers.findlaw.com/search-mapping.log" earliest=-1mon@mon | where isnull(PAMapped)`